# Numba jitted len() is slower than pure Python len()

Tags: python, numpy, numba

I'm learning numba and encountered with this "strange" behavior that I don't understand.
I tried with the following code (in iPython, for timing):

```py
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

@nb.njit
def nb_len(seq):
    return len(seq)

def py_len(seq):
    return len(seq)

##
t = np.random.rand(1000)

%timeit nb_len(t)
%timeit py_len(t)
```

The results is as follows (actually the second run due to compilation of numba):

```
258 ns ± 1.37 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
137 ns ± 0.964 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
```

The pure python version is twice as fast as numba version. 
I also tried with signature `@nb.njit( nb.int32(nb.float64[:]) )` but the result is still the same.

Did I make mistake somewhere?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It isn't the len() part that is adding the time.  Calling a jit function with input parameters adds overhead, and this is the time difference you're seeing.

```
import numba as nb

def py_pass(i):
    return i

@nb.njit()
def nb_pass(i):
    return i

%timeit py_pass(1)
%timeit nb_pass(1)
```

#### Result with input parameters

```
102 ns ± 0.371 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
165 ns ± 0.783 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
```

Interestingly, if you don't need to pass anything to the jit function, it is faster:

```
def py_pass():
    return 1

@nb.njit()
def nb_pass():
    return 1

%timeit py_pass()
%timeit nb_pass()
```

#### Result without input parameters

```
96.6 ns ± 0.278 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
75.8 ns ± 0.221 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 3):

As the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59390219/5393381) stated it's not because of the `len` function in this case but because the call to the numba function is actually slower than the call to a normal Python function.

### What makes a `jit`-ted function different?

To understand why calling numba jitted functions is slower one has to understand that a numba jitted function isn't a function anymore. It's a dispatcher object:

```
import numba as nb
@nb.njit
def nb_len(seq):
    return len(seq)
print(nb_len)  # CPUDispatcher(<function nb_len at 0x0000027EB1B4E798>)
```

This `CPUDispatcher` instance represents (possibly) multiple compiled functions that are generated based on the decorated function.

That means when you call the `CPUDispatcher` instance there are multiple steps:

- Get the type of the arguments.
- If there's no suitable compiled function for these types of arguments compile the decorated function using the types of the arguments.
- Sometimes: Convert the arguments to the corresponding numba types.
- Call the compiled function.

All of these steps add overhead compared to a non-decorated function. Especially if there's no suitable compiled function and the dispatcher needs to compile the function - or - the input types needs converting (only happens for Python types like: lists, sets, dicts) calling the `CPUDispatcher` will be a lot slower - these types are being deprecated at the time of writing in numba 0.46 partly because of that, see ["2.11.2. Deprecation of reflection for List and Set types"](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.46.0/reference/deprecation.html#deprecation-of-reflection-for-list-and-set-types).

## In your case

In your case the first call to the jitted function will be significantly slower because of the compilation.

Any subsequent calls will only be slightly slower because numba has to get the argument types, check that there is already a compiled function, and then calling that compiled function. Interestingly the additional time depends on the number of arguments and the number of already compiled "overloads" of that function. Often this additional time is insignificant because the function does much more than calling `len`.

### Compilation time

Even though the function is quite simple the compilation on the first call takes a significant amount of time:

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

def first_call(seq):
    @nb.njit
    def nb_len(seq):
        return len(seq)
    return nb_len(seq)

@nb.njit
def _nb_len(seq):
    return len(seq)

def subsequent_calls(seq):
    return _nb_len(seq)

t = np.random.rand(1000)
_nb_len(np.ones(1, dtype=np.float64))

%timeit first_call(t)
# 29.8 ms ± 1.57 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
%timeit subsequent_calls(t)
# 384 ns ± 6.02 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

### Conversion time

Also if numba needs to convert the argument it will be a lot slower. This happens only for Python types that numba cannot handle directly, for example lists:

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

@nb.njit
def nb_len(seq):
    return len(seq)

arr = np.random.rand(10_000)
lst = arr.tolist()

nb_len(arr)
nb_len(lst)

%timeit nb_len(arr)
# 354 ns ± 24 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
%timeit nb_len(lst)
# 14.1 ms ± 950 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

### Summary

- Numba functions have some additional overhead compared to normal Python functions. So make sure you do "enough" stuff that numba is good at optimizing, otherwise a plain Python function will be faster, more flexible and much easier to debug.
- Function calls in numba functions can really be different from function calls outside of numba functions. So `len()` in `nb_len` and `len()` in `py_len` can have totally different run-times. However in this case the run-time is almost identical. But it's generally good to be aware of it.
- Depending on the argument types a numba function can (behind the scenes) be quite slow, especially if dealing with Python types as arguments or return type!

Comment: Thank you for taking the time giving a very helpful explanation.

Comment: @FirstnameLastname You're welcome! Please don't forget (if you haven't already) to [upvote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) all helpful answers.